# How to trace a failed SEPA bank transfer

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account, wire-transfer, sepa

A UK bank initiated a transfer for a client of mine to my own account. The wire was in EUR and my account is an IBAN EUR account. 7 days passed and the money are not with me. They did not return to the sender either. After talking with my bank they told me my account supports only SEPA payments and because the sender did not use SEPA the transfer was not successful. I asked the sender to initiate a trace with Natwest, but no results for 3 days now. My bank claims they cannot trace since the money never reached them. Any experience with such a scenario? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My bank claims they cannot trace since the money never reached them.

Your bank is right. They can't generally trace this.

> I asked the sender to initiate a trace with Natwest, but no results for 3 days now.

Natwest should be able to trace and confirm it. This usually takes anywhere from 7 to 10 days.

Comment: Who should bear the expense for the trace then? The accounting of my client wants me to pay 45 GBP if my bank is to blame. I am not sure who's fault it is since I told them my account is SEPA and they failed to setup the transfer parameters according to the SEPA guidelines of Natwest. They didn't knew other types of transfer would fail. Neither did I. The first time I heard about it was when my bank told me after the problem. My account has a description, says it supports transfers from countries in SEPA. Like UK. The same client sent me money to Postbank in DE without issues before.

Comment: @BorisHamanov It would appear that the transferring bank (Natwest) should have known and therefore is at fault, since euro-denominated payments from non-Euro countries have had to [follow SEPA protocols since October 2016](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/retpaym/paymint/migration/html/index.en.html).