# Tracing a SEPA transfer : any official document available?

Tags: transfer, sepa

I sent a SCT (SEPA Credit Transfer) on a Sunday and the operation appeared on my bank statement on Monday.

More than a week later (8 days, no holidays on both countries) the beneficiary says that he still has not received it and the funds have not been returned to me.

We both double checked everything (IBAN, BIC, ...) and there is no typo or error. Moreover, this is not my first time sending SCT to this company and it always worked perfectly.

I asked my bank to trace the payment inside the SEPA network and give me an official paper : they confirm **by email** that the payment was made correctly but they refuse to give me any official document that could prove where the funds are currently located.

I find it strange because I know this can be done for international SWIFT wires traces (you get a document from the SWIFT network proving where the funds are).

At the time of this post, we are on SCT Rulebook version 1.3 : I can see there is a section 4.5 about "Inquiry process" but it has not yet entered into force (start from 17 November 2019) and I am not sure what is the current procedure right now.

What kind of **official document** can I legaly ask from my bank and what is the expected delay to get it ?

The question is about the legal procedure to know who is to blame, it does not cover the funds themselves (I guess I can ask for a "Request for Recall by the Originator" but I am not guaranteed to get the funds back, there will probably be fees and I will not know who is responsible for this mess).

Note : I believe this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87098/how-to-trace-a-failed-sepa-bank-transfer) because I am the sender, the transfer was made as SEPA and I ask about the documents (the other question was asked by the beneficiary and the problem was from not sending as SEPA).

Comment: Section 5.7 (near bottom of p62) has "_provide an explanation to the Originator and/or the Beneficiary Bank as to how a Credit Transfer Instruction has been processed and provide to the Originator all reasonably requested information in the event of a dispute;_" but I suspect the definition of "reasonable" -- if defined at all -- will be in "Annex IV - Risk Management" which has restricted circulation.